# Is it possible to print a double float

Tags: unix, awk

Say i am currently printing a column as a floating point by

```
awk '{printf "%4.3f \n", $1}'
```

Is it possible to instead `%4.3(some letter/s)` to make it a double float?

Comment: There is no "double float".  Double is not float.  Besides, what exactly do you mean by "make it a double float"? You should provide an example.

Comment: This was actually very helpful because I was told to do this by my professor but  have not been able to figure out exactly what it means.  I'll have to ask her to clarify for me. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect she means https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format. Double precision is what modern (POSIX, etc.) awks use by default to represent a float. When a modern awk prints a float it's using the equivalent of the double-precision C datatype "double" while an ancient awk would be using the equivalent of the single-precision C datatype "float". So I guess the answer to your question is "no", there is no letter/s you can add to the printf spec to change that default which already IS a "double float". See https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Arbitrary-Precision-Arithmetic for more info.

If that's NOT what your question is about then edit it to clarify and provide concise, testable sample input and expected output.

Comment: Okay so just making sure, this is more of an internal process of either the computer or the program being run whether they use 32-bit(float) or 64-bit(double-float)? So if my program used double-float it would continue to use it unless for some reason i were to go in and tell the program to use float instead?

Comment: Not quite. If the program uses double-float then that is **IT**, end of story.